# Using RecordRef to Work with Multiple Tables

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-nav

I have a group of tables that I need to the integer key from and I would like to be able to pass in any of them into a single and get the next value for the key.

I believe that RecordRef is the way to do this, but the code so far doesn't seem quite right.

I am trying to build a function that will take a table record and then return an integer value, that integer value will be the next record for the primary key.  IE: if the last record's key is is 62825 the function will return 62826.

```
FunctionA
BEGIN
  Id := GetNextId(SalesRecord);  //Assignment not allowed
END;

FunctionB
BEGIN
  Id := GetNextId(CreditMemoRecord);  //Assignment not allowed
END;

GetNextId(pTableReference: RecordRef) rNextId : Integer
BEGIN
  CASE pTableReference.NUMBER OF
    DATABASE::SalesRecord: BEGIN
      //Find last Record
      pTableReference.FINDLAST;
      lFieldRef := pTableReference.FIELD(1); //Set to the PK field
    END;
    DATABASE::CreditMemoRecord: BEGIN
      //Find last Record
      pTableReference.FINDLAST;
      lFieldRef := pTableReference.FIELD(10); //Set to the PK field
    END;
    ... //do more here
  END; //CASE

  EVALUATE(rNextId,FORMAT(lFieldRef.VALUE)); //Get the integer value from FieldRef
  rNextId := rNextId + 1; //Add one for the next value
  EXIT(rNextId);  //return the value
END;
```

With this code I am getting the error "Assignment is not allowed for this variable." on the Function Call to GetNextId

Idea of the Table Structure:

```
Table - SalesRecord
FieldId, Fieldname, Type, Description
1 id integer PK
2 text1 text(30)
3 text2 text(30)
4 dec1 decimal
5 dec2 decmial

Table - CreditMemoRecord
FieldId, Fieldname, Type, Description
10 id integer PK
20 text1 text(30)
30 text2 text(30)
40 dec1 decmial
50 dec2 decmial
```

Comment: An example would be useful to see what you expect the record & function to return.

Comment: `SalesRecord` and `CreditMemoRecord` in functions A and B are record variables right? Not RecordRef variables? This is wat your error about. You cant pass record variable as RecordRef parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put function like this in both tables

```
GetNextId() rNextId : Integer
BEGIN
  RESET;
  FINDLAST;
  EXIT(id+1);
END;
```

an then call it from record variable

```
FunctionA
BEGIN
  Id := SalesRecord.GetNextId();
END;

FunctionB
BEGIN
  Id := CreditMemoRecord.GetNextId();
END;
```

This is common practice I believe.

Answer (score 1):

You mean "GetNextValue" get next record? I don't quite understand your use-case.

If you want to pass in a generic record, then you'll want to use the VARIANT data type. This is a wildcard type that will accept Records from any table, and allow you to return records from any table.

This is untested, but hopefully give you an idea of how they could work;

```
LOCAL NextRecord(VAR RecVariant : Variant)

IF RecVariant.ISRECORD THEN BEGIN
  RecRef.GETTABLE(RecVariant);

  // RecRef.NUMBER is useful for Database::"Customer" style comparisons

  RecRef.NEXT;
  RecRef.SETTABLE(RecVariant); // Might not be necessary

END;
```

Comment: I cleaned up the code example to make it more clear, I am just looking to get the next key value not the whole record.  Thanks.

Comment: So you've got multiple keys in a table and for a particular record you want to get the 1st Primary Key, then the Next?

Comment: The Variant piece looks like what I need but now I am getting a table initialization error when I attempt to use RecRef.GETTABLE(RecVariant).  I am wondering if it's maybe not fully supported in NAV 2009 SP1

Comment: When writing the code, I had thought I needed a .OPEN before the GETTABLE, so perhaps the behaviour changed between versions. Ultimately you can use .FIELD and .CURRENTKEYINDEX to figure out what the next FIELDNO should be.

If you can't use .GETTABLE, perhaps send through a RecordID instead which has .TABLENO.

Comment: This is the solution I wanted to implement as it did not require a modification to the underlying table (it's an outside integration with direct SQL Inserts), however I just get uninitialized table errors in 2009SP1, I've reviewed the code for newer versions and it looks like it should work in 2015 and above (maybe even as early as 2009R2).